# Intents? How to register to be alerted for incoming emails?

Tags: android

Extreme Android developer newbie here...well, new to Android development, not development in general.

I want to write an application that gets notified when emails come into the device, and takes various actions based on data in the email (subject, sender, to, etc).  I think what I have to do is create a BroadcastReceiver with an IntentFilter.  The problem I'm having is figuring out what Intent(s) I need to "listen" for.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no broadcast `Intents` for incoming emails. Email is handled at the application level, and there are lots of possible email clients.

Sorry!