# Reacting to notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I need my app to react when there is a notification about incoming email, sms or call.

I can use the NotificationManager to create notifications, but not read them from other apps.

I have looked at AccessibilityManager, but I can't quite figure that out either.

Any pointers or examples? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Email. I don't think you can do it using standart libraries. Probably it has sense to search third party API
2. SMS. You shuold use BroadcatReceiver for ACTION ="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"
3. CALL. Use PhoneStateListener

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {

```
   @Override 
   public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber) { 
                 //do smth
   } 
}, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: Could you point me to how stop this reaction I start when the SMS is read?

I mean I need to activate a LED when I get a message, and turn it off when it is read. 

Should I react to the phone being unlocked and let that turn of my notification?

Answer (score 0):

You should register [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and listen for specific intents.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [this](http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html) for incoming SMS.

Email might be [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439610/intents-how-to-register-to-be-alerted-for-incoming-emails) in general, but [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/eac04c2a99eb681c?pli=1) is a discussion about recieving notifications from Gmail client.

Incoming calls were discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android).